# Communicating with an unsecure device: Security by Abstraction Vs HTTP HTTPS callback

Tags: security, ssl, arduino

I have a web-server with an SSL certificate, and an unsecured device on a GSM/GPRS network (arduino MKR GSM 1400). The MKR GSM 1400 library does not feature a SSL server, only an SSL Client. I would prefer to use a library if that's possible, but I don't wanna write a SSL Server class. I am considering writing my own protocol, but I'm familiar with HTTPS and will make writing the interface on the webserver side easier.

- The GSM Server only has an SSL Client
- I am in control of both devices
- Commands are delivered by a text string
- Only the webserver has SSL
- My C skills are decent at best

I need the SSL Server to be able to send commands to the Arduino Device, but I want these commands to be secured (The arduino device opens and closes valves in a building).

[image]

The other option would maybe have some sort of PSK, but I wouldn't know where to start on that. Is there an easy function to encrypt and decrypt a "command string". I also don't want "attackers" to be sending commands that I've sent before.

My Basic question is, does this method provide some reasonable level of security? Or is there some way to do this that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Can you install `stunnel` on your Arduino? If so, problem solved. You will have a TLS stream between any client and the stunnel (configure certificates properly, etc...) and the stunnel locally will forward the content to the non TLS enabled software. `nginx` or `haproxy` may be able to do the same but are far more complex than `stunnel` (different goals). `pound` is similar to `stunnel`. Also note that your schema is kind of backwards (and you should have put that as text): the party initiating the communication is normally the client and the server listens for requests.

Comment: Another way to look at it, not suitable for realtime or complex multiplexing, but that does not need to install anything extra: have a program on your Arduino that loops indefinitely and like each minute grabs a specific HTTPS URL, on which there will be details of a command to execute; if something is needed. If so it would execute it and then contact another HTTPS URL to report the result of the actions. Work is more complicated on the HTTPS webserver to coordinate requests and replies; but like that your Arduino stays as an HTTPS client and your webserver as an HTTPS server.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: I'm not sure if there is stunnel available for the Arduino platform, Arduino is just a very limited system.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek that's an interesting point and that lead me to believe that maybe I can just open a socket from the arduino SSL client library, and on the server side keep the socket open until a command is required and then respond.

Comment: Yes but you will still need some logic on the client side to make sure the socket is left open or more precisely properly handle any shutdown there and just reopen the socket. Because it may be closed (if no traffic) for various reasons not necessarily under your direct control (TCP/IP settings on both hosts, and various firewalls among the two). A one shot fire may be simpler, otherwise you are very much reinventing websockets for HTTP, which provide full duplex exchanges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in a perfect world there would be a better approach, you are currently working within the limits of what your tiny system provides.

In this situation I find your approach reasonable: the server simply tells the client using an insecure transport that there is some message awaiting (i.e. sends some trigger message, actual payload does not matter) and the client then retrieves the message using a transport which both protects the message against sniffing and modification and also makes sure that the message actually came from the server (i.e. authentication).

Since the trigger message from the server contains no actual payload (arrival of the message itself is enough payload) an attacker could not modify or fake the message to create insecure behavior in the client. The worst what could happen is that some attacker will either block the client from getting the trigger messages or that the attacker fakes trigger messages even though there is no actual command waiting from the server.

If the last case is seen as a problem it could be dealt with a rate limit, i.e. if server did not return any command although the client received a trigger message than the client will wait some minimum time before contacting the server again, no matter if a trigger message was received or not. The first case of the attacker being able to block messages from the server is harder to deal with since in this case the attacker is likely able to block further communication between client and server too - but this is a problem for any kind of communication between client and server.